# GeckoWebBrowser and HtmlElementCollection

Tags: c#

I'm new with GeckoBrowser. The problem is in my `SetText` method:

```
void SetText(string attribute, string attName, string value)
{
    // Get a collection of all the tags with name "input";
    HtmlElementCollection tagsCollection =
            geckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");

    foreach (HtmlElement currentTag in tagsCollection)
    {
        // If the attribute of the current tag has the name attName
        if (currentTag.GetAttribute(attribute).Equals(attName))
        {
            // Then set its attribute "value".
            currentTag.SetAttribute("value", value);
            currentTag.Focus();
        }
    }
}
```

But I am getting an error on this line:

```
HtmlElementCollection tagsCollection =
        geckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
```

The error is:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'Skybound.Gecko.GeckoElementCollection'
    to 'System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElementCollection'
```

Any ideas how to work around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `GetElementsByTagName` method on `GeckoDocument` does not return an `HtmlElementCollection`, it returns a `GeckoElementCollection` (which, in turn, contains `GeckoElement`s, not `HtmlElement`s).

So you need something like this (untested):

```
void SetText(string attribute, string attName, string value)
{
    // Get a collection of all the tags with name "input";
    GeckoElementCollection tagsCollection = geckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");

    foreach (GeckoElement currentTag in tagsCollection)
    {
        // If the attribute of the current tag has the name attName
        if (currentTag.GetAttribute(attribute).Equals(attName))
        {
            // Then set its attribute "value".
            currentTag.SetAttribute("value", value);
            currentTag.Focus();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Worth an upvote from me ... plus I'm about to direct the poster back here from his duplicate post on CodeProject